# boot-repair: An error occured during repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

My grub partition got corrupted and I've been trying to fix it for a few hours. Right now it is empty, just formatted.

Partitions on this device are as follows, in their order on the disk:

- `/dev/sda2` (24 MB, used to be the grub partition)
- `/dev/sda1` (350 GB, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
- `/dev/sda3` (70 GB, Arch Linux)

I've run boot-repair from my Kubuntu Live USB. It ends by saying

```
An error occurred during the repair.
```

This is the full error report from boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GTzXgC5Ngw

Errors from the above full text:

```
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20190414_0811 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa65
boot-sav version : 4ppa65
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa65
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, bionic, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed boot=casper maybe-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash --- maybe-ubiquity
ls: cannot access '/home/usr/.config': No such file or directory
```

And:

```
=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub2 of sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/etc/default/grub
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda2/etc/default/grub
lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
```

Every time I reboot the computer after that it just boots to a black screen with "Operating System Not Found". I am using an old-ish Sony VAIO (BIOS system).